# how to publish my app using Foursquare Secret? Security is concerned

Tags: api, security, foursquare

I made a site using Foursquare API, and want to publish it on my personal homepage, but I have the security concern with my Foursquare SECRET. 
I used ajax request in a JS file using the following format of URL, and I'm afraid clients would be able to read my Foursquare ID and Secret:

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20180325&ll=lat,lng&query=cafe`

I did search for a way to restrict accessible URL like Yelp does, but Foursquare doesn't seem to provide that method. What are the best way to secure my Foursquare Secret either/both on client-side or/and server-side? (I do not have much of a knowledge on back-end, but if a detailed information is provided, you'd be much appreciated, thank you all)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the users token instead of your Client_ID / Client_Secret.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?oauth_token=someUsersToken&ll=lat,lng&query=cafe
```

Your app is linked to that token.

Another suggestion would be to use a server as a proxy. Send all request from your app to your server then have your server make the request to foursquare, injecting the client ID and secret, then send the foursquare response back to your app.

Problem I see with using the user token exposed is, they could potentially use that token to impersonate your app with requests to foursquare.

You can check here for more info on foursquare's authentication.
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication